# Magento: Currency symbol dissapears in the case of configurable products once an option is selected

Tags: magento

Please guide me on how to solve this issue. The currency symbol (new Rs.) dissapears in the product view page once an option gets selected, even from the price which is next to the product image. I think this might be related to the js problem, because when the page loads it appears correctly,

Thank you very much for your time,

Comment: Hi Sulabh, I have managed to crack that, Are you still having trouble with this issue

Comment: yes...please post how you solved this.

Comment: would appreciate it if you can share how you have fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution that worked for me:

http://vithyamagento.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/magento-currency-symbol-dissapears-in-the-case-of-configurable-products-once-an-option-is-selected/

As a summary, in js\varien\product.js you need to replace the call to the formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat); to a custom formatting function, and then create that custom formatting function in js\varien\js.js

Answer (score 0):

Please add this Code where you want to display Currency Symbol for Product Price.

Get currency symbol for current store:

**Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();**

Get currency code for current store:

**Mage::app()->getStore()-> getCurrentCurrencyCode();**

Get currency symbol for a specify currency code:

**Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('EUR')->getSymbol();**

***Hope it'll work for you :)***

Comment: Thanks Ankur, this code fetched the symbol correctly. So you are correct partially, but the moment I select an option in configurable product, it again changes back to Rs. rather than a hindi crossed R symbol